# How can I avoid Sigma's sucking-in-rocks attack in Mega Man X 4?

Tags: mega-man-x4

I've got the majority of the final Sigma fight down to an art with Zero except for Sigma 3 when he does the attack where the big Sigma head spawns in the bottom left corner and sucks in rocks (I can post a video later if necessary).

When this attack starts I know if I can get to the top right corner and stay there I can avoid all damage, but getting up there I often take damage from the rocks being inhaled, and this tactic also completely forfeits my ability to deal damage (though I can just wait for the exhale attack which is much easier to work with). Bonus points for strategies that also work with X, but I was having this trouble with Zero.

It seems to be luck based, unlike Sigma's other 2 forms, but if there is any way to avoid him performing this attack *at all* that would be an even better hint.

Comment: Can you not destroy the rocks that are flying towards you?

Comment: @RavenDreamer not particularly well. You have to act fast, and IIRC if you standing slash you can destroy the blue robot head which is blocking you from being sucked in, since the Z saber attacks a bit behind too (I stand between the two heads that are on the ground)